# Does switchMap unsubscribe to subject during the false condition? Why does it reinitialise the value?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to clarify about the output!
Why does the out start again with 0, why does it not continue?

```
const { Subject, interval } = require('rxjs');
const { switchMap, filter,tap } = require('rxjs/operators');

// A timer observable that emits every 1sec
const timer$ = interval(1000)

// The subject that will be used a switch
const switch$ = new Subject();

// Emit timer data only when the switch is on
const subscription = switch$.pipe(
    filter(toggle => toggle),
    switchMap(toggle => timer$)
).subscribe(time => console.log('ms passed: ' + time))


// Simulation
setTimeout(() => switch$.next(true), 1000);
setTimeout(() => switch$.next(false), 4000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('-------'), 5500);

 setTimeout(() => switch$.next(true), 6000);

setTimeout(() => switch$.next(false), 7000);

setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 10000);
```

### **output**
ms passed: 0
ms passed: 1
ms passed: 2
ms passed: 3

ms passed: 0
ms passed: 1
ms passed: 2

Comment: ms passed: 0
ms passed: 1
ms passed: 2
ms passed: 3
-------
ms passed: 0
ms passed: 1
ms passed: 2

Answer (score 1):

switchmap unsubscribes from the previous observable when receiving a new value. Even though you are passing a reference to the same observable, the logic internally is (metacode):

```
_currentObs.unsubscribe();
_currentObs = newObs;
_currentObs.subscribe(...);
```

this causes the $timer to be unsubscribed and receive a new subscription, which are distinct instances from the previous one and starts at zero again